# JUnit 5 -- global timeout?

Tags: junit, junit5

In JUnit 5, what is the best way to enforce a global timeout for all tests?

I see that JUnit 4 has a `@Rule` feature, but this has been removed in JUnit 5.  And I would prefer not to have to copy-paste [`assertTimeoutPreemptively`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertTimeoutPreemptively(java.time.Duration,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable)) for every test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned the JUnit 4 [`@Rule`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13.2/org/junit/Rule.html) feature, which allows specifying timeouts on a per-test class basis using an annotated [`Timeout`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/index.html) field.  JUnit 5.5 has a direct equivalent in the [`@Timeout`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Timeout.html) annotation.  This can be applied to the class level in the same manner as the JUnit 4 rule, in which case it applies to all tests within the class and its `@Nested` classes.  It can also be applied to individual `@Test` or lifecycle (`@BeforeAll`, `@BeforeEach`, `@AfterEach`, or `@AfterAll`) methods.

Per the [JUnit 5 user guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-declarative-timeouts):

> The `@Timeout` annotation allows one to declare that a test, test factory, test template, or lifecycle method should fail if its execution time exceeds a given duration. The time unit for the duration defaults to seconds but is configurable.
>
> [...]
>
> To apply the same timeout to all test methods within a test class and all of its `@Nested` classes, you can declare the `@Timeout` annotation at the class level. It will then be applied to all test, test factory, and test template methods within that class and its `@Nested` classes unless overridden by a `@Timeout` annotation on a specific method or `@Nested` class. Please note that `@Timeout` annotations declared at the class level are not applied to lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 12):

Junit 5.5 does support "global timeout". Just have a look at [documentation of corresponding property knobs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-declarative-timeouts).

For example, try to open file `src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties` and paste there:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.timeout.default=42 ms
```

Answer (score 7):

Prior to version 5.5 of JUnit, it was not possible to enforce a global, preemptive timeout for tests in JUnit Jupiter.  This functionality was added as an experimental feature to JUnit 5.5.

To view the discussion around this feature, see the following issue: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/80